# How can I sum-up the results of a for-each loop in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSL so I don´t really know how to do this. I have a for-each statement that does some computations for each element of a type "cell". How can I sum-up the results and store them in a variable so I can display it? I have included a part of the code.

I hope someone knows the solution to this problem. Thank you for your time and effort!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">

<xsl:output media-type="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="object-map" match="/Data/Objects/*" use="@ExternalId"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <Data>
  <Objects>
    ...
    ...
    ...

    <xsl:for-each select="Data/Objects/Cell">
   <xsl:attribute name="PpXmlVer">
     <xsl:text>7.0</xsl:text>
   </xsl:attribute>

      ......................

      <!--Calculating Machine Time: -->
      <Cell>
        <xsl:attribute name="ExternalId">
          <xsl:value-of select="@ExternalId"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!-- calculated.-->
        <FlipMachineTime>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./FlipPlanedOccupationTime &gt; 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="here is a complicated formula to compute"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </FlipMaschineTime>
      </Cell>

      </xsl:for-each>

      Here I would like to have the sum of FlipMachineTime 
      for all encountered elements of type cell.

    ...........

  </Objects>
 </Data>
```

Comment: It would be good if you provide a simplified problem with a complete sample XML document and define what should be the output.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a variable to hold the FlipMachineTime nodes you have computed. Then you can sum the nodeset. Here is some sample code:

```
<xsl:variable name="flipMachineTimes">
  <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Objects/Cell">
    <FlipMachineTime>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="./FlipPlanedOccupationTime > 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="here is a complicated formula to compute"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </FlipMachineTime>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<total>
  <xsl:variable name="myTotal" select="xalan:nodeset($flipMachineTimes)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum($myTotal/FlipMachineTime)"/>
</total>
```

To get this to work, make sure you include the xalan namespace in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Comment: @Kaladze, most XSLT 1.0 processors (not just Xalan) also have the nodeset extension. Check your processor's documentation to see how to use it. Of course if you have access to XSLT 2.0, it becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @Kaladze: most of XSLT 1.0  processors support node-set() of EXSLT, see my answer to see how to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `exslt:node-set()` from http://exslt.org/common than the specific processor implementation being **EXSLT** much more portable on the various processors. In that case, you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
            extension-element-prefixes="exslt">

 <!-- staff -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For example in **Saxon 6.5** you should be able to use it like:

```
<total>
  <xsl:variable name="myTotal" select="exslt:node-set($flipMachineTimes)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum($myTotal/FlipMachineTime)"/>
</total>
```

If you set the stylesheet version to 1.1, that's easier (as it should be):

```
 <total>
   <xsl:value-of select="sum(exslt:node-set($flipMachineTimes/FlipMachineTime))"/>
 </total>
```

---

After seeing your gist, I think you are working on something huge and complex which can not be solved here with a simple question. There can be too many details that you might have omitted. However if it's just the case of displaying a value (where???) I can suggest this last thing.

Try to create a variable for each cell:

```
  <Cell>
    <xsl:attribute name="ExternalId">
      <xsl:value-of select="@ExternalId"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- calculated.-->
    <FlipMaschinenlaufzeit>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="./FlipPlanbelegungszeit &gt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="$planbelegungszeit - (($planbelegungszeit * ($organisatorischeAusfallzeit div 100)) + ($planbelegungszeit * ($stoerungsbedingteUnterbrechungen div 100)) + ($planbelegungszeit * ($nebenzeit div 100)))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </FlipMaschinenlaufzeit>
  </Cell>

  <xsl:varible name="a">
     <!-- paste here the code of xsl:choose inside the cell -->
  </xsl:variable>

 <!-- create other variables for each cell in the same way (use different names, like b, c ..) -->

 <!-- after the last cell, display the sum -->
 <xsl:value-of select="$a + $b + $c + ..."/>
```

Comment: @empo Thank you very much for your answer. I tried it but I get this error message when trying to display the value of "total". I have also tried to display the value of "myTotal" and got the same error: "a reference to variable or parameter ´myTotal´ cannot be resolved. The variable or parameter may not be defined, or it may not be in scope."

Comment: Which processor are you using?

Comment: And..how/where did you define `$flipMachineTimes`?

Comment: I´m editing this file in a software application called "Process Designer". How can I find out which processor I´m using?

Comment: More useful would be if you can show a bit of the transform you are testing. If you can't edit post, just add an answer.

Comment: Can I send you the entire file? It would be much easier. I can not include the code in a comment. It is to big :(

Comment: No you can't :) sorry. Post the fragment where you define the variables or [create a gist](https://gist.github.com/) and link it back here.

Comment: Note that if "Process Designer" supports XSLT 2.0, the way to do that is much easier.

Comment: So, the file contains text in German. "flipMachineTimes" is actually "FlipMaschinenlaufzeit" in the original file. I have posted the code here https://gist.github.com/1014654 The interesting part is at lines 157 - 191.

Comment: As I said, you have to define the variable `$FlipMaschinenlaufzeit`. Try it. I'm not able to help you now. I will be back to you later this evening to extend my answer.

Comment: There is no documentation available for Process Designer to state if it is XSLT 2.0 compatible. That is why I did a test and replaced xsl:stylesheet from 1.0 to 2.0 like this "xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" and also replaced "for-each" with "for each-group" as I have read that this is one difference bewteen XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. Running the new document it gave this error: "The stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document" From this I concluded that Process Designer 8.1.1 Release August, 2007 does not support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: "FlipMaschinenlaufzeit" is defined somewhere else in Process Designer. What I could find out is that is of type double. For example the document without modifications works just fine https://gist.github.com/1014806

Comment: I've extended my answer. I think that I can't offer further help, but my answer. Hope it helps.